# Execlp call bash without TTY

Tags: c++, bash, sockets, ssh, tty

I'm using some pipe and fork to execute a command like

cat file.tar.gz | myprogram -c "tar -zvt" -i "remoteMachineIp"

But if i do

myprogram -c "bash" -i "remoteMachineIp"

The bash is ok, but no tty.
Without the tty if i call the vim command it opens the vi messed.

How can i call the bash on execlp with the tty.

Code Example

```
if(cm->pid2==0){ //pipe and fork to send data to my execlp
close(cm->fout[0]);
dup2(cm->fout[1], 1);
execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", command.c_str(), NULL); // command is mycommand so is bash -c "bash"
}
else{
close(cm->fout[1]);
while((size=read(cm->fout[0], buffer, 2000)) > 0){
cm->message->send(buffer, size); //send the data to my program
}
//Close it and send the return code
```

The problem is the execlp returns the bash to me, but no tty
If i call ssh user@machine "bash" the bash comes with problem, but jut ssh user@machine its ok

How can i call the bash with the tty?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your concern is that the command you launch inherits `stdin` from its parent (`myprogram`) and its parent's `stdin` is the pipe that accepts data from `cat file.tar.gz`. You would like to run a child that is forced to read data from the tty, not the inherited `stdin` pipe.

You can open `/dev/tty` to get a reference to the tty. It will fail if there is no tty. For example:

```
close(0);
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR);
/* The file descriptor returned by open should be 0 */
```

However, I notice that you redirect the child command's `stdout` to a pipe to your program. If the command you are `exec`ing is interactive, this will not work. An interactive command needs to have both its input and its output connected to a tty. Launching an interactive command with its output connected to a pipe probably does not make any sense, regardless of whether you connect `stdin` to a tty.

By the way: why do you use `bash -c <command>` instead of `sh -c <command>` in your `execlp`? This way you introduce an unnecessary dependency on `bash` where all you really need is the standard POSIX bourne shell `sh`. `exec`ing through `sh -c` is the standard way to launch a command through a shell. This is what's done, for example, by `system()`.

Comment: i'm using the bash -c because the project needs it, all the programs called in the socket will use bash. Is there a way to use pipe and fork with tty?

Comment: Even if it's a `bash` script (as opposed to a generic `sh` script), you can still launch it with `sh -c <the-script>` as per the standard way to launch things. This works if it's a Python or Perl or lua script or anything else too.

Comment: "use pipe and fork with tty"? Well, your command's stdio will either be a pipe or it will be the tty. It cannot be both.

Comment: How can i execl my bash with tty?

Comment: I already said that in the answer: `open("/dev/tty", O_whatever);`. `dup2()` the result to whichever file descriptor you'd like to direct to the tty (0 for stdin, 1 for stdout, 2 for stderr).